# Any Web or Desktop Apps Out There Like Google Wave?

Tags: version-control, google-wave

Are there any existing or upcoming web or desktop apps out there like Google Wave?

Answer (score 5):

[Groove Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/groove/FX100487641033.aspx).  Ray Ozzie if probably kicking himself now that he's seen how Google applied [Operational Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation).

Answer (score 3):

[SHAREFLOW](http://www.zenbe.com/shareflow)! It's the future... Very similar to Google Wave only without the withdrawal of funding for the future ;]

Comment: I's a good one. I've tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the video I saw (presumably the same one everyone else saw who is reading this) I guess I would say that email, instant messaging, wikis, version control systems, and social networks are all "like Google Wave" at times. What's cool is that Wave mimics any of those. If you treat it like email, it acts like email, etc.

But is there one thing that has all or most of the functionality of Wave? Well, I guess GMail, because it groups conversations together, whereas most email systems treat each message as a separate thing. Plus it has both email and IM, with some integration between the two.

Or maybe a bulletin board / forum kind of thing, where anyone can edit anyone else's posts?

Answer (score 1):

37 Signals' [Persistent Chatrooms](http://campfirenow.com/) are similar to Google Wave in some ways.

Answer (score 1):

I got excited about Groove when it came out and in many ways Google Wave reminds me of that, the little I have seen. I have not looked at Groove for years now even though it is a part of MS Office. A lot of the problems that stopped the early versions of Groove being adopted are not present in Wave though or are no longer problems due to new technology so it has potential.

Answer (score 0):

[LysKOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LysKOM) apparently is similar as well.

Answer (score 0):

The PyGo Wave Server is an opensource implementation of Google Wave:

http://wavety.com/pygo-wave-server/

Haven't tried it, though.

Answer (score 0):

http://colayer.com">**Colayer** is based on the Similar concept as Google Wave. But unlike Google Wave, the product is quite mature.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Novell Pulse](http://www.novell.com/products/pulse/).  It's based on the Wave Protocol, but looks like it kicks Google Wave's butt in terms of interface and functionality.

I expect that we will see more and more Wave clients, both web and desktop, spring up in the near future.  If the Wave Federation protocol actually works, all these apps will work with all the providers and all your data from different providers can be integrated into the one client.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the real-time collaboration of Google Wave, then you might want to check out
[Etherpad](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/),
[Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/) and
[Sub-Etha-Edit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/).